# «Богатый репертуар первых блюд» — правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, словосочетания

В одной из передач на канале «РЕН ТВ» я услышала такую часть предложения.

**...богатый репертуар первых блюд** (естественно, о приготовлении еды).

Я никогда не сталкивалась с понятием "репертуар пищи", поэтому высказывание мне показалось нестандартным, *дискомфортным*.
Подскажите, правильно ли так говорить? (Примеров я не нашла.)

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже вначале выпала в осадок, но узрела оный на Грамоте.ру, в словаре Кузнецова. С пометой - разговорное.

[**2.** *Разг*. Запас, наличие чего-л. Р. чьих-л. развлечений. **Р. европейской кухни.**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80&all=x)

Comment: Спасибо, Галина, за дополнительную ссылку. Я обнаружила похожую вот здесь: http://www.endic.ru/kuzhecov/Repertuar-42247.html. Но **ни одного** достойного (даже похожего) примера употребления, кроме словарного, я не нашла. P. S. Очень-очень рада, что Вы снова с нами!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова В современной кулинарной литературе (включая плодовитых классиков типа Похлёбкина) очень много выражений о _репертуаре (такой-то национальной) кухни_ или _репертуаре блюд_. Найти можно гуглом на запрос "репертуар кухни блюд", с переходом на "книги". Лишь в единичном случае попалось "репертуар" в кавычках.

Answer (score 1):

Кузнецов примеры употребления репертуара стырил из "Большого академического словаря". Там и кухня, там и развлечения.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стырить-то Вы стырили, спасибо за словарную ссылку. Но Вы не обратили внимание на то, что в пример приводится сочинение господина Д. И. Писарева (1861, часть III). Полное предложение выглядит так: _Европеец доводит разнообразие пищи до последних пределов; как гражданин мира, он не ограничивается произведениями своей родины и питается всем, что приходится ему по вкусу; как человек занимает средину между животными, так европеец занимает средину между людьми; растительная и мясная пища достигают возможно полного равновесия в репертуаре европейской кухни образованных и зажиточных классов._

Comment: Про репертуар домашних развлечений я еще могу понять... Вот ссылка: http://az.lib.ru/p/pisarew_d/text_1861_moleshott.shtml А еще что-нибудь — свежее полуторавековой давности — Вам удалось обнаружить? Мне — нет.

Comment: Я не понял, на что надо обращать внимание. Я вижу, что последнюю часть предложения сократили для словаря, убрав одно слово - "возможно". Ну да, ещё формы глагольные различны в словаре и вашем примере. И что? На существование осмысленного словосочетания "в репертуаре европейской кухни образованных и зажиточных классов" это никак не влияет.  Тут наслаивание родительных падежей: репертуар кухни классов.